# What is missing from my use of std::fixed?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to simulate a plinko board, and within that program I've got a function that outputs the money assigned to each slot. I'm trying to use std::fixed and std::setprecision to output each value with two zeros after the decimal place, but each value is outputting as if I hadn't used fixed at all. What am I missing? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void ChipsAllSlots(int numChips) {
    const int NUM_SLOTS = 9;
    const int slotWinnings[NUM_SLOTS] = {100, 500, 1000, 0, 10000, 0, 1000, 500, 100};

    for (int i = 0; i < numChips; ++i) {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << slotWinnings[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    ChipsAllSlots(9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `slotWinnings[]` is of type `int`. `fixed` and `setprecision()` is not considered when outputting `int` values. If you want a decimal point and two 0 digits, just print `".00"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` affect only the output of floating point numbers. You output integers, so those manipulators have no effect. If you convert to floating point before inserting into the stream, or use an array of floating point in the first place, then you will see the `.00` that you're missing.

Comment: See I knew I was missing something dumb like that. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Jake If it helped please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as an answer.